# macOS 上の pyautguiで ] を入力する方法を教えてください

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui

`]` の入力の仕方です。 `[` の方は入力できました。
いつも入力しているキーボードで打たせても別の文字が入力されてしまいうまくいかず、インターネットで何度も調べましたが、どうしてもわかりませんでした。
わかる方どうかお願いします。

Comment: 入力されてしまう別の文字とは何か？とかWindowsからの類推だと使用しているキーボードの国別のマップやモード設定の違いとか、何かキーマップをカスタマイズする設定やソフトウェアが入っていないか？とか、そうした情報を質問記事に追記してみてください。

Comment: タイトルからすると，Python の pyautogui モジュールを使った記述で `pyautogui.press(']')` だけが期待したように動かないということでしょうか。それとも，macOS で日本語キーボード（'P' の右隣が '@'）を使っていて ']' が印字されているキーを押しても別の文字が入力されるということでしょうか。前者なら「（差し支えない範囲で）該当する記述」を，後者なら「']' で入力される別の文字」と「Shift + '2' で入力される文字」を質問に追記してください。

Comment: [ と記されてるキーを押すと@が入力されてしまいます　逆に ] と記されてるキーを押すと [ が入力されてしまいます

Answer (score 2):

> '[' と記されてるキーを押すと '@' が入力されてしまいます。逆に ']' と記されてるキーを押すと '[' が入力されてしまいます。

この現象から判断すると，英語（ANSI配列）キーボード（'P' の右隣が '['）を使っているのに，macOS が日本語（JIS配列）キーボード（'P' の右隣が '@'）と認識しているように見えます。

macOSでキーボードの設定を変えるには「キーボード設定アシスタント」（アプリ）を使いますが，起動するには以下の三つの方法があります。

(1) りんごマーク -> システム設定 -> キーボード -> キーボードの種類を変更
(2) ターミナルを起動して下記を実行

```
open /System/Library/CoreServices/KeyboardSetupAssistant.app
```

(3) Finder を起動し上記のパスを辿り KeyboardSetupAssistant.app を開く

「キーボード設定アシスタント」が起動したら，その指示に従うと最後にキーボードの種類が適切に選択されるので，「完了」します。
（追記）
「キーボード設定アシスタント」は少なくとも macOS10.13 (High Sierra) 以降で使えます。